# How to use stencil with third-party css library

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, typescript, stenciljs

I'm trying out [stenciljs](https://stenciljs.com/) for the first time. I want to build a little application and not just a reusable web component.

My question is if there's any possibility to add a third-party CSS library like **Bootstrap**, **Skeleton** or **Bulma** to my app.

I tried the following things, but none of them seem to work:

### Example 1:

Simply adding a CDN `<link rel="stylesheet" href="link-here">` in the `index.html` did not work.

### Example 2:

I installed the Bulma CSS library with `npm` and tried to import it in the `app.css` file like this:

```
@import "../../node_modules/bulma/css/bulma.min.css";
```

or

```
@import url("https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bulma/0.7.1/css/bulma.min.css");
```

The docs say that `app.css` is for global styles. But this method didn't work either.

How can I add a third-party CSS library to my stencil project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There might be a better way but the quickfix for this problem is importing the thrid-party CSS library in every component css file.

```
@import url("https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bulma/0.7.1/css/bulma.min.css");
```

Comment: Note: according to this this is an anti-pattern as it causes performance issues.

Read this article: https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2016/12/styling-web-components-using-a-shared-style-sheet/

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the solution from JiiB this is how to setup a global `app.css` stylesheet:

1. Create the `app.css` file within the `src` directory, for example at `/src/global/app.css`
2. Add `globalStyle: 'src/global/app.css'` to the `config` object in `/stecnil.config.ts`
3. Include the generated css file from `/build/app.css` in `/src/index.html`:

   ```
   <link href="/build/app.css" rel="stylesheet">
   ```

Comment: While app.css is loaded as a global css, styles defined here have no effect on components where shadow has been set to true.  To make things work you would have to not set shadow to true in the component decorator.

Answer (score 0):

My solution to using global styles was to just avoid the shadow-dom. Did this by passing `scoped=true` to the `Component` decorator.

```
@Component({
 tag: "my-component",
 styleUrl: "my-component.css",
 scoped: true, // <- This makes sure the component doesn't have native encapsulation
})
```